# Unable to connect to SQL Server database in my ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have tried to connect to a SQL Server database using the following steps:

[image: Tools In MenuBar of Visual Studio]

```
-> Tools -> "Connect To Database"
```

"Add connection" gave me the server name to use:

[image: Add connection]

Test connection succeeds:

[image: test connect succeeds]

But after clicking on "OK", this error pops up:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 2):

The steps you've described for connecting to the database are for the Server Explorer in the IDE -- the error dialog and message clearly indicate this. This is not related to an ASP.NET Core project. These steps can be performed w/o any solutions/projects opened in the IDE.

It's likely an issue with your installation. Try a "modify/repair" install, or a even a clean install. If the issue persists, open a ticket with the Visual Studio team. To open a ticket, from inside the IDE, at the top right corner, click the icon for sending feedback (next to the "Live Share" icon) and follow the prompts.

Please note that not being able to create a database connection in Server Explorer will NOT prevent you from coding an ASP.NET Core app that connects to that database.

Comment: It won't prevent me from ado.net sqlclient coding. But, In linq dbml file or entity framework file, I will not be able to drag and drop the table to create a table object. I've repair it once.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've solved my above error by [temporary workaround] replacing the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" assembly with the older version of visual studio 2019, this assembly is present in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE".
you'll find the above assembly in the original answer(go to this below link).

Taken from : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966#T-N1506125